# Why is this .each function working wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function to print the image dimensions of all `<img>` having the attribute `[proto]`.

When I try the function with this `each` method, it only returns a function.

What is the mistake?

```
function size(){
    var $img = $('img[proto]');
    $($img).each(function(){
        var height = $(this).height;
        var width = $(this).width;
        $(this).parent().find('p').remove();
        $(this).parent().append('<p class="size">' + width + '-' + height + '</p>');

    });
}
size();
```

Comment: *"its only giving back a function"* - Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: change `$($img)` to `$img` since it is already jquery object no need to wrap in `$()`

Comment: ^^ correct, but worth pointing out also that it would not stop it working.  jQuery is smart enough to spot that and "just work".

Comment: `.width` -> `.width()`. `.height` -> `.height()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are functions not properties, height and width:

```
var height = $(this).height();
var width = $(this).width();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change you elements declartion. Because you do it like this: `$($('img[proto]'))`. This way you cast your elements two time into jQuery.
2. `width` and `height` are functions, not properties. So you need to add brackets.

---

```
function size() {
    $('img[proto]').each(function() {
        var height = $(this).height(),
            width = $(this).width();
        $(this).parent().find('p').remove();
        $(this).parent().append('<p class="size">' + width + '-' + height + '</p>');
    });
}

size();
```

---

I would even prefer to only get the elements you needed once. The way you did it casts `this` four times into an jQuery object and search two times for the parent. The performance could be saved.

```
var element = $(this),
    parent = element.parent(),
    height = element.height(),
    width = element.width();

parent.find('p').remove();
parent.append('<p class="size">' + width + '-' + height + '</p>');
```

---

And if you want to execute the function directly, you can use an IIFE or just remove the function around and execute it directly.

```
(function() {
    $('img[proto]').each(function() {
        // ...
    });
})();
```

Comment: one more question: is there a reason your version is not working with: $(window).resize(function(){
  size();
});

Comment: No, this should work fine. You could even write it shorter: `$(window).resize(size);`. If you have any problems, let me know or show me your code. There would be something else wrong then ...

Comment: uuch. i made a nother stupid mistake. time to sleep. sorry bothering you and thanks a lot.